# How to fix error : 'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I tried install the COCO API in win10 with code

```
git clone https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi.git
cd cocoapi/PythonAPI
make
cp -r pycocotools <path_to_tensorflow>/models/research/
```

In step 3, i got a error :

```
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

i tried fix it, then i got a problem is i dont have path gnuwin32

What is gnuwin32 ? and how to fix error "make" is not recognzied ??

Comment: `make` is program often used to compile C/C++ code and Python's module sometimes have C/C++ code too. Probably you would have `make` if you install Window Visual C/C++ or some of its element. `gnuwin32` is group of Linux programs converted to Windows.

Comment: see GNUWin32: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/ and list of packages: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html. Check [make for WIndows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm)

Answer (score 2):

'make' is a program that can be run on Linux. On windows, you can't run it. You have to use Visual Studio or other compile tools.

You are trying to build COCO API on your hand.
But it may be so complicated for you, especially on Windows.

I recommend install COCO API using pip

Usually, you can run like this :

```
pip install pycocotools
```

But on Windows, you may met some error.
In that case you can run a modified verision.

Try this :

```
pip install git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#egg=pycocotools^&subdirectory=PythonAPI
```

If it is installed successfully, you don't need to build COCO API by yourself.

I hope it help you.

Comment: You can also run `pip install pycocotools-windows` as suggested here: https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/issues/415#issuecomment-627313816 that is up to date with the cocodataset master branch (as of writing)